# Difference - WISP from ISP

Tags: wireless

How does WISP work and where does it connect it to? Will it connect to a Satellite or do you need Fibers to establish connection? In short what Gateway or headend device does it connect to?

Comment: The same as *any* ISP: via any technology. What gear a WISP uses is, likewise, a vast array of possibilities.

Comment: https://uwn.com/en/faq/ - What is a WISP or Wireless Internet Service Provider?

WISPs use fixed wireless broadband technology to deliver the same high speeds and service of traditional broadband providers but delivered wirelessly as opposed to through buried cables.

So basically, no fibers, just pure wireless?

Comment: Yes, the cpe to isp link is wireless -- thus the *W* in WISP. What they use varies. How their POPs (radio towers) are connected also varies.

Answer (score 2):

WISP Setup Provider (Wireless Internet Service Provider) with networks built around wireless networking. Technology may include commonplace Wi-Fi wireless mesh networking, or proprietary equipment designed to operate over ***open band*** 900 MHz, 2.4 GHz, 4.9, 5.2, 5.4, 5.7, and 5.8 GHz bandsor ***licensed frequencies*** in the UHF band (including the MMDS frequency band) and LMDS

[image]

WISP Setup Provider (Wireless Internet Service Provider) are predominantly in rural environments where cable and digital subscriber lines are not available. WiMax is expected to become mainstream in the near future,the current called prewimax, bringing with it dramatic changes to the marketplace by increasing the number of inter operable equipment on the market and making mobile data transmission feasible, increasing the utility of such networks in rural environments. However, high-bandwidth wireless backhauls are already common in major cities, providing levels of bandwidth previously only available through expensive fiber optic connections. this linke is good reference for [WISP](http://trueinet.com/wisp%20setup%20provider.html)

Comment: Does WISPs provide the same bandwidth rates from tradiitonal ISPs? How do you find WISPs in your locally?

Answer (score 0):

I currently work for a WISP; we have 3 fiber connections that reside at the edge of our network, and we use point-to-point and point-to-multipoint wireless links to interconnect a backbone network that pulls in traffic from our subscriber access layer. We could use satellite at the edge connections if we needed to, but fiber is available, so that's what we use. A network is a network, so just like your network at home it doesn't make a difference if it's satellite, fiber, coax, DSL; a default route is a default route. Whatever technology is available with the right mix of price and performance.

Comment: Hi bro, so it still goes through a Fiber from the Edge to the Core?

Comment: They make a good point by putting this question on hold; even my answer is somewhat of a single-case example. In our network, the answer is yes; fiber to the core(s) and wireless distribution elsewhere. The answer from @gadeliow is a more generic, appropriate answer and applies to most WISP configurations.